# Android Text to speech not working in some phones

Tags: android, text-to-speech

This may not exactly be apt for this forum but I couldn't find a better option... I have made an android application that converts my text to speech using ANDROID TTS. The application worked fine in the emulator and also on HTC Wildfire S.

I uploaded it to the marketplace then downloaded it on a Samsung Galaxy S with Android 2.2 (FROYO) it auto downloaded ANDROID TTS from market but it dosn't work. The API does speak the text written but not in different languages that it used to and does on the Wildfire 5.

What's wrong? Do I need to install languages or something?

Comment: Do you perform a check whether TTS-Data for active language is installed (e.g. by `checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);`)?

Comment: yes i am checking that...

 Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
          startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

Comment: And if not found you start an Intent like this one:              `installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);`?

Comment: ya i even do that when i receive the result form "startActivityForResult(....)" and for phones not having tts engine it goes to android market and downloads it but then also if i translate for ex: "BONJOUR" in french it speaks as it is in english